# Equivalent System.Data.Linq.Binary in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Can anyone help me for convert this code in .net core :

```
    private static string GetValueFromModelValue(object formValue)
    {
        //Test to determine if its binary data. If it is, we need to convert it to a base64 string.
        Binary binaryValue = formValue as Binary;
        if (binaryValue != null)
        {
            formValue = binaryValue.ToArray();
        }

        //If the above conversion to an array worked, then the following will cast as a byte array and convert.
        byte[] byteArrayValue = formValue as byte[];
        if (byteArrayValue != null)
        {
            formValue = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayValue);
        }

        return formValue.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types in `System.Data.Linq` are not available in a version of .NET Core and .NET Standard (currently 1.0 - 2.0).

Since no caller can pass in a `Binary` object on .NET Core, you can either remove the code or put it inside a preprocessor define (this example assumes building for .NET Core 1.1):

```
#if !NETCOREAPP1_1
Binary binaryValue = …
if (binaryValue != null)
{
    …
}
#endif
```